# How do I interpret postgresql deadlock message?

Tags: postgresql, deadlock, psql

I'm running a Postgresql 9.5.2 server, and I'm occasionally seeing a message like:

> ERROR: deadlock detected
>   Detail: Process 1234 waits for ShareLock on transaction 3042999324; blocked by process 5678.
>   Process 5678 waits for ShareLock on transaction 3042999328; blocked by process 1234.
>   Hint: See server log for query details.
>   Where: while locking tuple (5389,30) in relation "asset"

If it contains any information about the row or column that's causing the deadlock, it will help me debug the big ugly [common-table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-with.html) that's causing the error in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out while looking up the correct terminology to use while asking my question: tuple refers to the row's [ctid](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-system-columns.html), a system column on every row indicating the physical location of the version of the row in question. (When a row is updated, Postgresql keeps the old version around for a while in order to fulfill [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) guarantees.)

You can select the data simply with:

```
SELECT * from "asset" where ctid = '(5389,30)';
```

However, if you wait too long (like I did), an [autovacuum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM) job might clean up that version of the row if it's no longer in use.